# magento-nofrills block additions not working

Tags: magento

I really like Alan Storm's book, but I still can't make progress after 16 hours of trying!

I have a working payment method, but I want to add a block to the display of the available payment methods in One Step Checkout.

First step is getting a basic test to work....

If I target content, my test text appears as expected:

```
<checkout_onepage_index>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="core/text_list" name="rrtest_list"/>
        </reference>
        <reference name="rrtest_list">
            <block type="core/text" name="rrtest1">
                <action method="setText">
                    <text>ABCDEFGHIJ KLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ *************</text>
                </action>
            </block>
        </reference>
</checkout_onepage_index>
```

But, if I target the block I really want, it doesn't work:

```
<checkout_onepage_index>
        <reference name="checkout.onepage.payment">
            <block type="core/text_list" name="rrtest_list"/>
        </reference>
        <reference name="rrtest_list">
            <block type="core/text" name="rrtest1">
                <action method="setText">
                    <text>ABCDEFGHIJ KLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ *************</text>
                </action>
            </block>
        </reference>
</checkout_onepage_index>
```

Nothing appears.  Why doesn't this work?

Answer (score 0):

Content block is a container (that means that every block that you add to it will be automatically rendered) and that's why it worked for you.

On the other hand checkout.onepage.payment block is derived (over an abstract class that doesn't change anything) from Mage_Core_Block_Template and blocks derived from this class don't automatically render your content.

You will have to change payment block's phtml file so that it will include your block

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml( 'rrtest_list_alias' ); // this outputs the html directly ?>
```

or

```
<?php echo $this->getChild( 'rrtest_list_alias' )->myFunctions()->toHtml(); // this allows you to call some functions on your block and then outputs the html ?>
```

and change your layout xml file to (note the as part):

```
<block type="core/text_list" name="rrtest_list" as="rrtest_list_alias"/>
```